# Count content inside quotes as one argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, arguments, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with node.js's discord.js module, I have a basic arguments detection system that uses the whitespace as the separator and puts the different arguments in an array, here's the important part of my code. (I'm using separate command modules using `module.exports`).

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.alias && cmd.alias.includes(commandName));
```

So for example when someone writes `!give foo 50 bar`. the args array is `['foo','50','bar']`
I want the `args` to not divide quoted parts of the command in the command, meaning if somenoe writes `!give "foo1 bar1" 50 "foo2 bar2"`. I want the `args` to return an array like this `['foo1 bar1', '50','foo2 bar2']` instead of `['foo1','bar1','50','foo2','bar1',]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way to do it, but I think it's comprehensible: we can scan every character and we keep track of whether we're inside or outside a couple of quotes and, if so, we ignore the spaces.

```js
function parseQuotes(str = '') {
  let current = '',
    arr = [],
    inQuotes = false
    
  for (let char of str.trim()) {
    if (char == '"') {
      // Switch the value of inQuotes
      inQuotes = !inQuotes
    } else if (char == ' ' && !inQuotes) {
      // If there's a space and where're not between quotes, push a new word
      arr.push(current)
      current = ''
    } else {
      // Add the character to the current word
      current += char
    }
  }
      
  // Push the last word
  arr.push(current)
    
  return arr
}

// EXAMPLES
// Run the snippet to see the results in the console

// !give "foo1 bar1" 50 "foo2 bar2"
let args1 = parseQuotes('!give "foo1 bar1" 50 "foo2 bar2"')
console.log(`Test 1: !give "foo1 bar1" 50 "foo2 bar2"\n-> [ "${args1.join('", "')}" ]`)

// !cmd foo bar baz
let args2 = parseQuotes('!cmd foo bar baz')
console.log(`Test 2: !cmd foo bar baz\n-> [ "${args2.join('", "')}" ]`)

// !cmd foo1 weir"d quot"es "not closed
let args3 = parseQuotes('!cmd foo1 weir"d quot"es "not closed')
console.log(`Test 3: !cmd foo1 weir"d quot"es "not closed\n-> [ "${args3.join('", "')}" ]`)
```